# I'm unable to use the new Xcode 4.3 debugger

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4.3

I’ve got strange debug error after moving my project from Xcode 4.0 to Xcode 4.3.

The project builds good, no error, but when I add something each time get errors on debug that I work with deallocated items.

For example simple line:

```
tableData=[[NSMutableArray] init];
```

gives nil ponter

```
tableData=0x0000
```

and  strange error in Output windows:

```
*** -[__NSDate description]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8382d30
```

In other places it could be not '__NSDate' but 'UITableView', 'NSString' and so on.
The same line in the same project with xCode 4.0 gives no error, but with Xcode 4.3 problems.

What is wrong? Could you suggest something.

Comment: I too have experienced this problem using LLDB in XCode 4.3. With a little more investigation it seems that after assigning a value to an ivar, the ivar declared immediately after it appears to have the value. The issue does not appear when using GDB

Answer (score 5):

My xCode is just installed.
I've resolved the problem.

Go in xCode
Product → Edit Scheme… → Info

Choose any other debugger and problem disappears. Later I played with this option and the problem never back.

I would suggest GDB, because LLDB still sometimes shows 0x00000 pointers right after allocation and initialization.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
tableData=[[NSMutableArray] init];
```

is not correct. The correct line is:

```
NSMutableArray *tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Further, you can use these lines to print the memory address:

```
NSLog(@"%p", tableData); // print the tableData memory address
```

or look in the debugger variable pane. Don't forget to release the memory:

```
[tableData release]; // release the memory
```

Comment: My question is more serios than just absence of declaration! Of course I did that. 'NSMutableArray *tableData;' is a class variable and I just do not show declaration and memory release, since it is not the question! I said that project builds GOOD, no errors. Whith your comment consider to declaration project build just is not possible. My question is still opened.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to show us the code that you think should work correctly.

Comment: Ok, It looked like you tried to add these line to your code: 'tableData=[[NSMutableArray] init];' . So, I replied as before. From your last answer, the problem seems to be related to LLDB. Just for curiosity: when the compilation worked good, did you use (GCC + GDB)? Did you try to compile with LLVM and debug with LLDB? (Probably, you tried to do that. I ask as certainty).